# Angular 2 - loading spinner

Tags: angular, angular-material, angular2-template, angular-material2

I want to use a material table and a material spinner.

I dont know how to show table only when spinner is loading and vice versa.

Comment: There's an example on how to do it on the documentation site (the title of the example is "Retrieving data through HTTP"): https://material.angular.io/components/table/examples

Answer (score 1):

Do something like this:

```
loading: boolean;

getTable() {
  loading = true;
  // Once table is done:
  loading = false;
}

<div *ngIf="loading">
    <mat-spinner></mat-spinner>
</div>

<div *ngIf="!loading">
   table here...
</div>
```

Or you could also set loading to true so that the spinner will show on page load. Though if i were you, I'd build a component/service that automatically does this anytime you are fetching data. Unless of course this is the only place you fetch data